# How to '\dotfill' at MathJaX

Tags: mathjax

I would like to produce something like that:
[image]

Does MathJax know a methode for `\dotfill`?

PS: *About MathJax* says me

```
MathJax v2.7.5
using web TeX fonts

MathJax.js v2.7.5
TeX Input Jax v2.7.5
HTML-CSS Output Jax v2.7.5
mml Element Jax v2.7.5
MathEvents Extension v2.7.5
MathMenu Extension v2.7.5
MathZoom Extension v2.7.5
TeX/AMSmath Extension v2.7.5
TeX/AMSsymbols Extension v2.7.5
TeX/begingroup Extension v2.7.5
TeX/noErrors Extension v2.7.5
TeX/noUndefined Extension v2.7.5
tex2jax Extension v2.7.5
Chrome v120.0.0.0 — woff or otf fonts
```

Comment: I've thought of a way that might do what you need, if you have access to modify the MathJax configuration.  Are you using MathJax v3 or v2?

Comment: @DavideCervone I added "About MathJax".

Comment: Are you willing to update to v2.7.9 (or better, v3.2.2) and switch to the CommonHTML output rather than HTML-CSS?  If so, I can probably get you something that would be like `\dotfill{a = b}{\text{(3)}}` to get you the output you are describing above.

Comment: Just to be clear, is this for a page that you manage (i.e., one where you can edit the MathJax configuration and change the version in use) or is it for a StackExchange site or some other site that you don't control?

Comment: No, I am sorry, this is www.matheplanet.com where I use MathJax. So I am not able to change the settings or whatever.

Comment: OK.  I'm sorry, I don't have a solution for you in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MathJax has no mechanism for doing that.  MathJax's internals are very different from TeX's, and it does not use the boxes, glue, and leaders that TeX does to make such a thing possible.